# How to write SQL query for this Scenario?

Tags: mysql

An interviewer asked me this question, 
You are given two tables with columns as L1,T1 for table1 while T,Name for table2. Write a SQL query to get the desired result.
[image]

I'm still stuck on how to write the query to get the desired output.

Used this, `SELECT table1.L1, table2.Name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.T1 = table2.T;` but this way it won't CONCAT the output for Name wrt L1.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: You cannot guarantee this output, because there is no way of ordering table1 in prescribed manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an aggegation function as GROUP_CONCAT for obtain the comma separated result for name

```
  SELECT table1.L1,GROUP_CONCAT( table2.Name ORDER BY table2.Name ASC SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM table1 
  INNER JOIN table2 on table1.T1 = table2.T
  GROUP BY table1.L1 
  ORDER BY FIELD(table1.L1,'X','Y','Z')
```

withou aggegation function you get result on separated  rows  .. instead with group by an group_concat you obtain all the  name related  to a one l1 on the same  row

Comment: @Strawberry   .. order by and separator added  .. thanks for suggestion  .,

Answer (score 2):

You join the two tables using [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) (Inner Join). Then use `GROUP BY` to get aggregated data, and then eventually utilize [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) function to achieve comma separated names. See below:

```
SELECT table1.l1, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.name) 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.t1 = table2.t 
GROUP BY table1.l1
```

Answer (score 2):

use this query

```
SELECT table1.L1, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.name separator ', ')
FROM table1 AS table1
INNER JOIN table2 as table2 ON table1.T1 = table2.t
GROUP BY table1.L1
```

SQL fiddle here to test it live  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac3a3/1/0

Comment: your should explain better your question  a  simple  "use this query"  don't explain the answer  ..

Answer (score 1):

This sql will get the result.

`SELECT L1, GROUP_CONCAT(name) from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on T1 = T GROUP BY L1`